# Big json file in php returns error

Tags: php, json

This is the code I use to print my json that I read from a file to a web page. The json file which i read releases.json is fairly big, it is 6.97 mb to be exact.

```
<?php

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('./releases.json'), true);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

But it returns this following error:

```
502 Bad Gateway
PhpStorm 2017.3.2
```

Thank you and when I try it with a smaller json file it works

Comment: Probably you're running out of memory (or hitting the memory limit per process). See your PHP logs, it should tell you what's happening.

Comment: Why are you double decoding it?

Comment: You could replace all that code with `readfile('./releases.json');`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix oops haha thank you